# How to list mysql data alphabetically with the first alphabets as select option

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login page and want to display schools as a select option. Now the name of the schools are stored in mysql database and I want to echo the name of the school alphabetically with the first letter of the alphabets but each time o try I the first letters keeping repeating it self

I have tried to get the school, then get the first letter and echo both but it does not work

```
<?php

$queryy = SELECT * FROM school ORDER BY school;
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$queryy);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$letter = strtoupper($row['school'][0]);
$aGroup[$letter][] = $row;
echo $aGroup[$letter][0]."<br />";
}
?>
```

I expect the options to be in this form

```
A
Adajesus primary school
Adams secondary school
B
bubenduf boys school
benbee primary school
best inland school
C
child care school
L
life Streams College
love and hope school
```

.

but the actual output is

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
C
C
L
L
L
```

Comment: `echo $aGroup[$letter][0]." ".$row['school']."<br>"`

Comment: `echo  $row['school']."<br />";`

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\multi\new.php on line 42
Array IGWEBUIKE GRAMMAR SCHOOL AWKA

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\multi\new.php on line 42
Array INFANT JESUS

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\multi\new.php on line 42
Array SAINT OBI

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\multi\new.php on line 42
Array ST JOHN OF GOD SECONDARY SCHOOL AWKA

Comment: http://portal.ppsscanambra.net/EnterDetails/GetRegNo.aspx                        the choose school is what i want to do in php when the schools are already on my database and i use mysqli .God bless

Comment: can you please print `$aGroup[$letter]` outside of the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
Change mysqli_query format
<select class="show-tick" required="" id="school_name" name="school_name" >
              <option value="">Choose School</option>
              <?php
              $queryy = "SELECT school_name FROM schools ORDER BY school_name";
              $result = mysql_query($queryy);
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['school_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['school_name'] ?></option>  
              <?php }
              ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: how then do i get the Alphabetical grouping to be done sir?

Comment: SELECT school_name FROM schools  GROUP BY school_name ORDER BY school_name